# Ceiling fan/light won't work after painting and reinstalling

Tags: ceiling-fan

I removed my ceiling fan to wrap the beam on which it was installed. Upon reinstalling, it didn't work. So... i threw it out thinking it was old. I didn't change anything on the wall switches, i simply undid the wire nuts, white/white, red/red, black/black, grounds together. This fixture was controlled by a switch for the fan, and a dimmer for the light..
Now i have a new fan/light which only work together with one switch. I tested the wires on the ceiling and only the red comes from the switch, i planed to eliminate the dimmer. There is a remote feature that must me used. Surprisingly, this new one does not work either. I retested the red and black wires, i have power in the right place but still won't work. Any Help???

Thanks
dave t

Comment: Post pictures?  Before after?

Answer (score 0):

You simply have to get in there and start testing and identifying your conductors. Don't use a non-contact tester.  Use a genuine and voltage tester.